# Cannot access nvidia-settings or use HDMI with Quadro 3000m

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, hdmi

I've just done a fresh install of oneiric on a Dell Precision m6600 with a nVidia Quadro 3000m.  I can log in to Unity 3D, but if I try to start nvidia-settings, I'm told "you do not appear to be using the nVidia X driver".  Also, HDMI out doesn't work.

The automatically generated xorg.conf is very short and doesn't appear to be using the nVidia driver:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Device"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection
```

However, if I run nvidia-xconfig, it will replace the xorg.conf with, among other things, `Driver "Nvidia"` line, but when  I restart the computer, lightdm won't even start at all.

This all occurs whether I activate nvidia-current or nvidia-current-updates by the "Additional Drivers" GUI. In either case, the GUI says "This driver is currently activated and in use". (obviously not).

How should I go about getting nvidia-settings and HDMI-out to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For posterity:

Apparently I missed the memo where Quadro is only just beginning to be supported under Ubuntu. I disabled the Optimus feature in BIOS and reinstalled, and it worked fine.